# Using display:table for layout / presentational purposes?

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

Some people think both HTML `<table>`s and `display:table` should be used for tabular data exclusively.

I instead think that `display:table` doesn't have any implicit semantic meaning and that it can be used for layout / presentational purposes, as well as for displaying tabular data.

Is there anything wrong with using `display:table` for layout purposes? If so can you provide more details?

References to specifications etc. are welcome.

Comment: I'll say this: just because something looks like a table doesn't mean it's a table.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Markup is markup (and HTML is markup designed to convey semantics). Presentation is presentation.

Answer (score 2):

When I need a shrink-to-fit block element that allows me to vertically center content, then I will use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` as needed.

I will not use a `<table>` to create a page size grid. Instead I will use a CSS framework like Twitter Bootstrap.

However, I will use a one-row/one-cell table is I need it to fix a centering problem that needs to work in older IE browsers that do not support CSS tables.

As a professional developer, I need to get the job done in a timely fashion and sometimes I will add extra mark-up if that what it takes to get the task finished.